# Is there any way to implement the Send trait for ZipFile?

Tags: rust, zip

I want to read a `.zip` file in a different thread by using the [zip crate](https://crates.io/crates/zip).

```
extern crate zip;

use zip::ZipArchive;
use zip::read::ZipFile;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::BufReader;
use std::thread;

fn compute_hashes(mut file: ZipFile) {
    let reader_thread= thread::spawn(move || {
        let mut reader = BufReader::new(file);
        /* ... */
    });
}

fn main() {
    let mut file = File::open(r"facebook-JakubOnderka.zip").unwrap();
    let mut zip = ZipArchive::new(file).unwrap();

    for i in 0..zip.len() {
        let mut inside = zip.by_index(i).unwrap();

        if !inside.name().ends_with("/") { // skip directories
            println!("Filename: {}", inside.name());
            compute_hashes(inside);
        }
    }
}
```

But the compiler shows me this error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::io::Read: std::marker::Send` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:10:24
   |
10 |     let reader_thread= thread::spawn(move || {
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `std::io::Read` cannot be sent between threads safely
   |
   = help: the trait `std::marker::Send` is not implemented for `std::io::Read`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::marker::Send` for `&mut std::io::Read`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `std::io::Take<&mut std::io::Read>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `zip::crc32::Crc32Reader<std::io::Take<&mut std::io::Read>>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `zip::read::ZipFileReader<'_>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `zip::read::ZipFile<'_>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `[closure@src/main.rs:10:38: 13:6 file:zip::read::ZipFile<'_>]`
   = note: required by `std::thread::spawn`
```

But the same works for the type `std::fs::File`. Is it necessary to fix the `zip` crate or is there any other method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is **a limitation of the `zip` crate's API** and you can't really change anything. The problem is that the file `ZipArchive` is created by calling `new` and passing a reader -- something that implements `Read` and `Seek`. But these are the only requirements for the reader (in particular, the reader doesn't need to be `Clone`). Thus, the whole `ZipArchive` can only own one reader.

But now the `ZipArchive` is able to produce `ZipFile`s which implement `Read` themselves. How does that work if the whole `ZipArchive` only has one reader? Through sharing! The only reader is shared between the archive and all files. But this sharing is not thread save! A mutable reference to the reader is stored in each `ZipFile` -- this violates Rust's core principle.

This is a known issue of the crate and is being discussed [on the GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/mvdnes/zip-rs/issues/14).

---

So what can you do now? Not a whole lot, but a few possibilities (as mentioned by the library author) might be OK for your use case:

- You could decompress the whole file into memory first, then send the raw data to another thread to do calculations on it. Something like:

  ```
  let data = Vec::new();
  BufReader::new(file).read_to_end(&mut data)?;
  let reader_thread= thread::spawn(move || {
      // Do stuff with `data`
  });
  ```

  But if you just want to compute a cheap hash function on all files, loading the contents into memory is probably slower than computing the hash on the fly and might be infeasible if your files are big.
- Creating one `ZipArchive` for each thread. This might be very slow if you have many small files in your archive...

---

A tiny hint: starting a thread costs time. You often don't want to start a thread for each unit of work, but rather maintain a fixed number of threads in a thread pool, manage work in a queue and assign work to idle worker threads. [The `threadpool` crate](https://crates.io/crates/threadpool) might serve your needs.